# Java - Map two objects containing List of objects(objects which have different naming but same function)

Tags: java, dozer

I have two classes:

```
public class1{
    private int id;
    private List<Student> students;
}

public Student{
    private name;
    private address;
}

public Class2{
    private int id;
    private List<Person> person;
}

public Person{
    private personName;
    private location;
}
```

I have to map/copy values from class1 to class2. I tried to use dozer bean mapper API, but I could not map List of Student with List of Person as they have different field names but same function. Please help me with dozer mapping or if there is other solution, highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: do you want to copy the values of List of Student to Existing List of Person? or New List of Person?

Comment: existing Person

Comment: you can add the values by extracting the List of Student and then add it in the existing List of Person without using Dozer.

Comment: Introduce an interface that expresses the common parts and use that. Classes aren't "equal" because of having similar fields but when providing similar behavior. Like get/set name...

Comment: @LKTN.25 I cannot do that as I have 1000s of objects in that list and it would be time consuming

Comment: you will iterate the values of Student and then Add it to the List of Person.

Comment: @GhostCat How do I implement that? My Class1 is populated by consuming a restful end point's response. I have to copy those values in class1 and produce it to consumer of my rest end point

Comment: @LKTN.25 I could do that but it will bring my performance down

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public static List<Person> mapValues() {

    List<Student> students = class1.getStudents(); // Assuming you have getters of students field
    List<Person> persons = class2.getPersons(); // Assuming you have getters of persons field
    for(Student student: students) {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setPersonName(student.getName);
        person.setLocation(student.getAddress);
        persons.add(person);
    }
    return persons;
}
```

Comment: I could do this but it will bring the code performance down. I am trying to use dozer API as an alternate. Thanks!